# Why do I get parse error after my if then else statement in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, parse-error

Im getting parse error on my if then else statement and I dont understand why. I have checked the functions, and as far as I can tell all of them are getting the arguments they need, so I dont understand why this is happening. Im very new to haskell so help in understanding this would be deeply appreciated.

```
replace :: [(Int,Int)] -> String -> String
replace xs ys = if translate (manipulator (fst (convert xs)) (snd (convert xs)) ys) /= ""
then take (fst (convert xs)) ys ++ (manipulator (fst (convert xs)) (snd (convert xs)) ys) ++ drop (snd (convert xs)) ys
else take (fst (convert xs)) ys ++ stjerner (snd (convert xs) - fst (convert xs)) ++ drop (snd (convert (xs)) ys

--get parse error here, see picture.
stjerner :: Int -> String
stjerner 0 = ""
stjerner int | int > 0 =  "*" ++ stjerner (int -1)
manipulator:: Int -> Int -> String -> String
manipulator low high xs = take high (drop low xs)
convert :: [a] -> a
convert [a] = a
```

[picture of parse error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSIWP.png)

Comment: it looks like you have an unclosed parenthesis on the line above. This really isn't very idiomatic Haskell, using this many nested parentheses should be rare. Consider using the `$` operator instead.

Comment: You use `convert xs` a huge number of times. You should use something like `let (f,s) = convert xs in ...` and then use `f,s` directly. Note that `convert` crashes is the length of `xs` is not one. This looks likely to be wrong.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69235216/2) is how your code should have been written. see if it is easier to spot the error there.

Answer (score 1):

The last expression in you `else` clause --- `drop (snd (convert (xs)) ys` -- is misparenthesized. You've got 3 open parens but only 2 close parens. I think you meant `drop (snd (convert xs)) ys`.